# Clean-Up the "complex" tag

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request, meta-tags

[complex](/questions/tagged/complex) seems to be a meta-tag. I looked through some of the questions and it only seems to be used for a (subjectively) very complex problem.

<strike>207</strike> 49 questions are tagged with it.

- I cleaned up this tag, it should be made a [synonym of complex-numbers] now

[complextype](/questions/tagged/complextype) has some disambiguities, not sure what to do with that:

- [xml datatype](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_complextype.asp). Example: [XML Schema + complexType element + Alternative to sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153711/xml-schema-complextype-element-alternative-to-sequence)
- complex in c : [Complex types using OpenMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311742/complex-types-using-openmp)
- complexType in sql - [EF4 SPROC Complex Type Mapping - Problem with ROW_NUMBER()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424925/ef4-sproc-complex-type-mapping-problem-with-row-number)

#### Tasks (see Giles answer):

1. <strike>cleanup everything in [complex](/questions/tagged/complex) and [complextype](/questions/tagged/complextype) that does not refer to complex numbers / the xml complex data type</strike> Done
2. make [complex](/questions/tagged/complex) a synonym of  [complex-numbers](/questions/tagged/complex-numbers)

Someone needs to to the synonymizing now.

**EDIT May/2012** I just cleaned up some questions from [complex](/questions/tagged/complex) again. The tag is still likely to be misused with "complex sql queries", "complex anything stuff" and "the complex xml type"

Comment: Good call! I bet there's a `simple` or `easy` tag as well.

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello nope :D and difficult neither.

Comment: @Pekka'sReputationBordello I think these were burninated in an earlier purge. There's a [tag:simplify], which is mostly meta but might have a few occurrences about [the theorem prover](http://kind.ucd.ie/products/opensource/Simplify/) or a function in some computer algebra systems (e.g. [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8073530) [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7638514)).

Answer (score 10):

Whoa there, many questions use it to mean complex numbers, which is also covered by [complex-numbers](/questions/tagged/complex-numbers). There's also [complextype](/questions/tagged/complextype) which at a first glance looks like a mixture of complex numbers and complicated types.

I propose the following:

1. Go through [complex](/questions/tagged/complex) and [complextype](/questions/tagged/complextype), removing the tag when it's used as a meta-tag.
2. Make [complex](/questions/tagged/complex) a synonym of [complex-numbers](/questions/tagged/complex-numbers), which should reduce its misuse.

As I write: 207 × [complex](/questions/tagged/complex), 58 × [complex-numbers](/questions/tagged/complex-numbers), 74 × [complextype](/questions/tagged/complextype). I propose to keep [complex-numbers](/questions/tagged/complex-numbers), even though it's the minority, because it's clearer.

Comment: There's also one occurrence for [complex network](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602790/good-graph-complex-networks-libraries) (yes, [this is a technical term](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_network)).

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to retag everything that is not the meta tag and burninate the rest? Do we really need a complex tag, that can be misinterpreted?

Comment: @örs Maybe, but I don't think the misuse is so widespread, I'd prefer to save [tag:complex] for complex numbers.

Comment: okay, I'll go ahead and retag those questions in the next few days.

Comment: I cleaned up the [complex] tag. Can you make it a synonym of complex-numbers?